# Discord bot unable to send messages in java using JDA

Tags: java, api, discord, discord-jda

My discord bot does all the neccaserry things so that on paper it should work but it doesnt

when ran the console/terminal prints as follows:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
details. SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation. SLF4J:
See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further
details. [main] INFO JDA - Login Successful! [JDA MainWS-WriteThread]
INFO WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket [JDA MainWS-ReadThread]
INFO JDA - Finished Loading!
```

Class Main.java below:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try {
            net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA api = JDABuilder.createDefault("********************").build();
            api.addEventListener(new MyEventListener());
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Class MyEventListener.java below:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
public class MyEventListener extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        if (event.getAuthor().isBot()) return;
        
        Message message = event.getMessage();
        String content = message.getContentRaw();
        MessageChannel channel = event.getChannel();
        
        if (content.startsWith("?test")) {
            channel.sendMessage(":thinking:");
        }
    }

}
```

when i put `createDefault("********************").build();` the *********** is the bots token, it is correct

Comment: You [didn't call queue()](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19\)-Troubleshooting#nothing-happens-when-using-x).

Comment: The console warnings have nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call the `queue()` on `channel.sendMessage(":thinking:");` which returns a [`MessageAction`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/restaction/MessageAction.html) (An implementation of `RestAction<Message>`. For more info see links below.

More details:

[Nothing happens when using x](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19%29-Troubleshooting#nothing-happens-when-using-x)

[RestAction in JDA](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html)